# How to convert nested for loops with if condition to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a horrible method that extracts data from a DataTable and converts it to a desirable formatted DataTable. I'm sure there is a much nicer way to do this in LinQ but I'm not really experienced with it. I would appreciate if somebody could show me a nicer solution.

Heres the code

```
private static void ExtractImportLayoutFromExcelDt(DataTable importDt, DataTable dtExtracted, int languages)
    {
        // The number of Locale colums included in the excel file. 
        for (int x = 0; x < languages; x++)
        {
            // The total number of friendlynames-keys / language included in the excel.
            for (int j = 0; j < dtExtracted.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                var row = dtExtracted.Rows[j];
                DataRow tempRow = importDt.NewRow();
                // Filling in the 3 columns. (FriendlyName - LocaleID - Text)
                for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        tempRow[i] = row[i];     // Friendly names: This is always going to be column 1 [0].                          
                    }
                    else if (i == 1)
                    {
                        tempRow[i] = Regex.Match(dtExtracted.Columns[x + 1].ToString(), @"\d+").Value; // LocaleIDs: Getting rid of non numeric characters from this column.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempRow[i] = row[x + 1];
                    }
                }
                importDt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For a starter it is hard to read with all these improper named variables (if you need comment, rewrite). What did you come up yourself so far?

Comment: Honestly Linq is better suited to convert `foreach` than `for`.

Comment: are you totally sure you need the innermost `for` loop there?

Comment: The innertmost for loop is to go through the 3 columns in the datatable, first column contains data about friendlynames second is the locale and third is the actual translation for the friendlyname.

Comment: true, but what's the point if you `if` each option anyway?

Comment: well you are right...

Comment: OK im going to edit the post so its clearer what s going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would rewrite inner `for` loops

```
for (int x = 0; x < languages; x++)    
    foreach (DataRow row in dtExtracted.Rows)        
        importDt.Rows.Add
        (
           row[0], 
           Regex.Match(dtExtracted.Columns[x + 1].ToString(), @"\d+").Value; // LocaleIDs: Getting rid of non numeric characters from this column.
           row[x + 1]
        );
```

`DataTable.Rows` collection has overload of `Add` method, which accept an array of objects:  [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This looks a lot better even tho its not linq.

Comment: @SóskuthyAndrás, `importDt.Rows.Add` creates a side-effect (adding new row). it will still require `foreach` to add rows, even if I prepare `IEnumerable<object[]>` data using Linq query (which I expect to be longer and not so readable)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if LINQ could be of any help here, but apart from rewriting the entire mapping logic I would at least split this method into two:

```
   private static void ExtractImportLayoutFromExcelDt(DataTable importDt, DataTable dtExtracted, int languages)
    {
        // The number of Locale colums included in the excel file. 
        for (int x = 0; x < languages; x++)
        {
            // The total number of friendlynames-keys / language included in the excel.
            for (int j = 0; j < dtExtracted.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                AddRow(importDt, dtExtracted, dtExtracted.Rows[j], x+1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AddRow(DataTable table, DataTable dtExtracted, DataRow originalRow, int language)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        row[0] = originalRow[0];
        row[1] = Regex.Match(dtExtracted.Columns[language].ToString(), @"\d+").Value;
        row[2] = originalRow[language];
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this but in this case is more like abuse of Linq but if you do it for educational purposes ..The main power of LINQ is when you want to enumerate or filter for example collections not in cases like this.

```
    public static void ExtractImportLayoutFromExcelDt(DataTable importDt, DataTable dtExtracted, int languages)
    {
        Enumerable.Range(0, languages)
            .ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                Enumerable.Range(0, dtExtracted.Rows.Count)
                    .ToList().ForEach(j =>
                    {
                        var row = dtExtracted.Rows[j];
                        DataRow tempRow = importDt.NewRow();
                        AddRow(importDt, dtExtracted, x, row, tempRow);
                    });
            });
    }

    private static void AddRow(DataTable importDt, DataTable dtExtracted, int x, DataRow row, DataRow tempRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                tempRow[i] = row[i];     // Friendly names: This is always going to be column 1 [0].                          
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                tempRow[i] = Regex.Match(dtExtracted.Columns[x + 1].ToString(), @"\d+").Value; // LocaleIDs: Getting rid of non numeric characters from this column.
            }
            else
            {
                tempRow[i] = row[x + 1];
            }
        }
        importDt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
    }
```

Comment: For me these long LinQ statements are less readable then nested loops and stuff but I will try to get a hang on it.